# A Sweetematical Puzzle

Tags: mathematics

There are $n$ sweets in a bag,

 $6$ of the sweets are orange.

 The rest of the sweets are yellow.

Hannah takes a random sweet from the bag

 She eats it.
Hannah takes another random sweet from the bag

 She eats it.

 The probablity that she eats two orange sweets is $1 /3$
.

Prove that $n^2-n-90=0$

Comment: I don't understand why is  this question being downvoted.

Comment: Most likely because many people think, that this is general mathematics (without the "puzzle" component) and so the tag doesn't apply.

Comment: Probably been downvoted because this is an exam question that you haven't referenced

Comment: As Adam alludes to, this seems to be more of a math *problem* than a math *puzzle*. Puzzles should generally involve the usage of math in a clever, non-straightforward way, which this question doesn't appear to have

Comment: @PiIsNot3 is exactly correct. You probably could still have snuck the straightforward math problem in by choosing some other finishing line; I bet the reaction would have been vastly different if you had instead asked us to "show that Hannah first ruined the perfect construction materials for a candy triangle, and then for a candy square right after that"

Comment: Solving this problem just involves mechanically applying standard formulas. It's a test of whether you learned how to compute probabilities, not a puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is stated that $\frac{6}{n} \cdot \frac{5}{(n-1)}=\frac{1}{3}$ from which $n(n-1)=90$

Comment: Great! Yoy got it!